# In ANDROID STUDIO when i added a component it is invisible and it is only visible in the side screen this is the screenshot-

Tags: android

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: This is the image of the android studio

Here is the code of activity_main.xml-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:rotation="0"
    android:rotationX="0"
    android:rotationY="0"
    android:scaleX="0"
    android:scaleY="0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Can anyone help me with that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete scaleX and scaleY or give them value 1.